# Highlight Selected Row & Columns

Tags: excel, vba

I have this code which is below. The highlight is always enable. I am trying to find out  how can i create something to enable/disable whenever i want.
Thanks in advance.

```
  Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)
Static xRow
Static xColumn
If xColumn <> "" Then
    With Columns(xColumn).Interior
        .ColorIndex = xlNone
    End With
    With Rows(xRow).Interior
        .ColorIndex = xlNone
    End With
End If
pRow = Selection.Row
pColumn = Selection.Column
xRow = pRow
xColumn = pColumn
With Columns(pColumn).Interior
    .ColorIndex = 6
    .Pattern = xlSolid
End With
With Rows(pRow).Interior
    .ColorIndex = 6
    .Pattern = xlSolid
End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Try,

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    
    Cells.Interior.Color = xlNone
    If Range("a1") = "" Then Exit Sub 'Set operation according to a1 cell
    With Target
        .EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = 6
        .EntireColumn.Interior.ColorIndex = 6
    End With
End Sub
```

It would be nice to insert the activeX control Checkbox in the sheet and set the behavior accordingly.

[image]

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    
    Cells.Interior.Color = xlNone
    'If Range("a1") = "" Then Exit Sub
    If CheckBox1 Then Exit Sub
    With Target
        .EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = 6
        .EntireColumn.Interior.ColorIndex = 6
    End With
End Sub
```